# 500: Internal Server Error undefined index Symfony3

Tags: json, doctrine, symfony

I'm trying to send from api rest controller (Symfony3) a object collection but get an error. "{"error":{"code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error","exception":[{"message":"Notice: Undefined index: Bar"

```
/**
 *
 *
 * @Get("/api/bars.{_format}", defaults={"_format"="json"}, options={"expose"=true}, name="api_bars")
 * @View()
 */
public function getBarsAction (Request $request) 
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $session = $this->get('Session'); 
    $repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Bar');
    $bars = $repository->findAll();

    foreach ($bars as $bar) 
    {
        $id = $bar->getId();
        $name = $bar->getName();
        $bars[] = array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$name);

    }

    $view = $this->View($bars,200);
    return $this->handleView($view);       
}
```

And the Bar Entity is:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Bar
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Bar")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\BarRepository")
 */

class Bar
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="location", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $location;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */

private $description;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Waiter", mappedBy="Bar")
*/ 
protected $waiters;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Table_", mappedBy="Bar")
*/ 
protected $tables;

/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Stock_food", mappedBy="Bar") */

private $stockfoods;

/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Stock_drink", mappedBy="Bar") */

private $stockdrinks;

public function __construct() 
{
    $this->waiters = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->tables = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->stockfoods = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->stockdrinks = new ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Bar
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set location
 *
 * @param string $location
 *
 * @return Bar
 */
public function setLocation($location)
{
    $this->location = $location;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get location
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLocation()
{
    return $this->location;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 *
 * @return Bar
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}


public function addWaiter($value){
    $this->waiters[] = $value;
}

public function getWaiters(){
    return $this->waiters;
}

public function removeWaiters($id)
{
    //optionally add a check here to see that $group exists before removing it.
    return $this->waiters->removeElement($id);
}

public function addTable($value){
    $this->tables[] = $value;
}

public function getTables(){
    return $this->tables;
}

public function removeTables($id)
{
    //optionally add a check here to see that $group exists before removing it.
    return $this->tables->removeElement($id);
}

public function addFood($value){
    $this->stockfoods[] = $value;
}

public function getFoods(){
    return $this->stockfoods;
}

public function removeFoods($id)
{
    //optionally add a check here to see that $group exists before removing it.
    return $this->stockfoods->removeElement($id);
}

public function addDrink($value){
    $this->stockdrinks[] = $value;
}

public function getDrinks(){
    return $this->stockdrinks;
}

public function removeDrinks($id)
{
    //optionally add a check here to see that $group exists before removing it.
    return $this->stockdrinks->removeElement($id);
}
```

}

Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace that allows it to spot where the wrong access happens?

Comment: I don't know how i can do it. This error only occurs when i try to send an  object collection, if i send one object no problem. Sorry for my limited English. Corrections are welcome.

Comment: For example '$view = $this->View($name,200);
        return $this->handleView($view); ' return "bar2" that it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem!!! I was related to association mapping. I've changed this:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Waiter", mappedBy="Bar")
*/ 
protected $waiters;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Table_", mappedBy="Bar")
*/ 
protected $tables;

/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Stock_food", mappedBy="Bar") */

private $stockfoods;

/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Stock_drink", mappedBy="Bar") */

private $stockdrinks;
```

For this:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Waiter", mappedBy="bar")
*/ 
protected $waiters;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Table_", mappedBy="bar")
*/ 
protected $tables;

/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Stock_food", mappedBy="bar") */

private $stockfoods;

/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Stock_drink", mappedBy="bar") */

private $stockdrinks;
```